# Is there a way to dynamically change the size and position of a checkbox when changes to a row height or column width are made?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that I'm using to record participant enrollment. I use a set of checkboxes and a ComboBox to allow the user to select a program and to select the relevant testing rounds. The ComboBox and Checkboxes are created using a Button click event, which ensures that the position and height of each component perfectly align with the cell which it is found within.

The issue is that the user may choose to change columns widths and row heights to fit data into specific cells (this is especially true with the "Additional Comments" column. These changes will throw off the alignment of the checkboxes and ComboBoxes with their respective cells.

I have tried utilising the Worksheet.Change event, but that function only throws an interrupt when the contents of the cells are changed. Other properties, such as the row height and column width, are not monitored. The user will have to manually move and resize the ComboBox and the CheckBoxes when such changes occur, which is tedious and reduces the quality of the Worksheet's presentation.

With an interrupt on change of row height, one can use the following VBA code:

```
private sub Row_Height_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'Special interrupt function

   Dim Row_Counter As Integer
   'Declare a row counter variable to store the row number

   Dim Row_Counter As Integer 
   'Declare a column counter variable to store the column number

   Row_Counter = 'Retrieve information from the interrupt
   Column_Counter = 'We know which column the CheckBox is found in

   Dim CheckBoxName As String

   CheckBoxName = "CB Test Round " & CStr(Row_Counter)
   'Name CheckBoxes in "Create Participant" macro using their position

   Column_Letter = Split(Cells(Row_Counter, Column_Counter).Address, "$")(1)

   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set TestRound1_CheckBox = ws.CheckBoxes(CheckBoxName)
   'Set the checkbox in question
   Set Cell_1 = ws.Cells(CStr(Row_Counter), Column_Letter) 
   'Find the cell where the checkbox is located

   With TestRound1_CheckBox
       .Left = Cell_1.Left + (Cell_1.Width / 2)
       .Top = Cell_1.Top + (Cell_1.Height / 2)
       .Right = ...

   End With
```

The issue is that I can't find such an interrupt. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not protect the sheet?

Comment: Thanks for your response SJR. I can certainly protect the sheet, but I don't want to restrict the user's ability to change the row heights to suit their needs. It will make the form less user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the alignment of any `shape` to the cell they are placed in, set their `Placement`-property to `xlMove` - in that case they stay within the cell even if they are resized. No need to handle any resize-event. In Excel, you set this property by right clicking on the control, select `"Format Control"`, `"Properties"` and select `"Move but not size"`. But you can do this also using VBA.

This code will set the property for all shapes of the active sheet:

```
Dim sh as Shape
For Each sh In activeSheet.Shapes
    sh.Placement = xlMove
Next sh
```

or just for the checkboxes you have

```
Dim sBox As CheckBox
For Each sBox In ws.CheckBoxes
    sBox.Placement = xlMove
Next sBox
```

If you create the Controls via code, you should simply set the property directly when you create them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment FunThomas!

Your proposed solution works, but it's not perfect. The movement of the checkbox is clumsy and doesn't always follow the change in the cell dimension perfectly. Is there no way to automatically move and centre the checkbox as soon as the cell dimensions are changed?